# How to set global route in GNOME Network Manager

Tags: gnome, network-manager, 17.10

*My apologies for the German screenshot. I don’t know how to force the settings window to be in English.*

When configuring networks, GNOME offers to configure the routes manually. However, it does not seem to allow a route with a netmask of `0.0.0.0`, as can be seen on the screenshot. If I change the mask to anything more specific, even `128.0.0.0`, the grey apply button in the upper right corner turns green.

Is that a bug? Is it on purpose – but which purpose? (On the command line, that is no problem at all.)

[image: Network Manager]

Comment: "*the grey apply button in the upper right corner **turns green***", don't you mean "*doesn't turn green*"?

Comment: No, it will turn green when I change the net mask. It will stay grey as long as the net mask is `0.0.0.0`

Answer (score 1):

## Network-Manager default GW handling

The network-manager always uses the last configured interface as default gateway. In case of LAN vs. WIFI this is almost always the WIFI. To avoid this, the option "Use only for resources on this connection" can be set to the WIFI.

The problem with this setting is: It only works in the LAN+WIFI environment. If the LAN is not present, the WIFI will not be used as default gateway.

## Network-Manager Dispatcher for special setups

The network-manager does not support profiles from the gnome GUI. But the network-manger dispatcher supports it. See the ArchWiki for a [WLAN/Eth toggle sample.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NetworkManager#Use_dispatcher_to_automatically_toggle_Wi-Fi_depending_on_LAN_cable_being_plugged_in)

```
# file: /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/wlan_auto_toggle.sh

#!/bin/sh

if [ "$1" = "LAN_interface" ]; then
    case "$2" in
        up)
            nmcli radio wifi off
            ;;
        down)
            nmcli radio wifi on
            ;;
    esac
fi
```

Comment: I don’t share that view. `/etc/network/interfaces` makes no mention of my interfaces, as everything is so automatic. On the other side, my network is there right in front of my eyes, I can enter values, that is _very easy_ indeed. (Or, would be, if it allowed me to save my values.)

Comment: @MPi Yes, the `/etc/network/interfaces` is empty in a default desktop ubuntu installation. Which is okay, since the network-manger does the configuration.  Have you tried to use a static (non-dhcp) configuration with a default gateway?

Comment: This question in not about how to do it all in config files. I suppose I could do that. The question is _why_ does Network Manager not allow me to configure the default route? The original question, BTW, was: Why does Ubuntu choose my WIFI over my LAN, and I landed in NM to change the metric…

Comment: The network-manager always uses the last interface, which was configured via DHCP as default gateway. In case of LAN vs WIFI, the WIFI always wins. If you don't want that, that the "Use only for resources on this connection" (the german version "Diese Verbindung...") for the WIFI.

Comment: And what happens when I pull the plug?

Comment: -> no default gateway. Added update to post.

Comment: This is a cool answer, thank you. I’m not sure how to handle it, though: It does not answer my question, but it does in fact solve my problem.